# Django Flatpage Giving 404 - But One Flatpage Works

Tags: django, http-status-code-404, django-flatpages

Using Django 1.9, Python 3.4...

Recently I modified my flatpages to take a custom field with the `class_prepared` approach:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#class-prepared

At this time, I already had one flatpage in the database at the URL `/about/`. After I implemented the above, I successfully tweaked the new field with data, and everything was working.

But then I added another flatpage at `/contact/` with the custom field, just to make sure everything was working, and it's giving a 404.

I first thought that my URLConf wasn't working. So I tested several variations, including the catch all in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/flatpages/) and specific entries like:

```
url(r'^about/', views.flatpage, {'url': '/about/'}, name='about'),
url(r'^contact/', views.flatpage, {'url': '/contact/'}, name='contact'),
```

But none of these worked.

I found some [references](http://western-skies.blogspot.com/2009/06/404-errors-with-django-flatpages.html) to the `SITE_ID` being wrong, and I confirmed mine is correct by querying the database, and checking the debugging information.

I also confirmed the data in the database, and the table `django_flatpage` shows 2 rows for the queries I did.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to actually delete this post, but then I realized... maybe someone else will have this same problem, and find this answer. I was banging my head against the wall, and I finally figured it out. It's weird, sometimes shortly after I post on SO or another SE board, I figure out what my problem was...

Anyway, in my `ExtendedFlatPageAdmin` my `fieldset` didn't include the `sites` field. Once I added this, I was able to go back to the Django admin, and resave the flatpage. Then it didn't give a 404.